# iOS - Region monitoring when device/user into new city?

Tags: ios, geolocation, clregion

As per iOS CLLocationManager API `startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges` will inform my app when there is significant change e.g. 500 mtrs or more.

But i want in my app like my app will get notified only when user/device enters into new city. App should automatically open if its in closed state.

NOTE: its not map/navigation application, so i don't want to my app keep monitoring user's location data and at the end drain device's battery.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: You're restricted to 64 regions, thus you will need to combine both significant location change and region monitoring. There is not build in city detect, you will have to build this yourself. Also you can not bring you app to the foreground, you are limited to a local notification.

Answer (score 1):

It will execute your application. (sorry that it's not a comment - but it's too long for comment).

See details below (from Apple Documentation)

To start region monitoring, configure the appropriate region object and pass it to the startMonitoringForRegion: method of your location manager. In iOS, registered regions persist between launches of your app. If a region boundary crossing occurs while your iOS app is not running, the system automatically wakes it up (or relaunches it) in the background so that it can process the event. In this case, the options dictionary passed to the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of your app delegate contains the key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to indicate that your app was launched because of a location-related event. During the relaunch process, you must recreate your location manager object and assign a delegate capable of handling region-related events. After you do that, the system delivers the region notification for which your app was launched. All of the regions you configured previously are made available in the monitoredRegions property of any location manager objects you create.

Comment: Thanks Sfirite. One question here. After configuring region object and pass it ot startMonitoringForRegion:, should user has to enable(keeping ON) location services always for boundary crossing notification? What if user has Turned off location notification and region boundary crossed and later on after few days if i start location service again. Will my app get notified that user has already crossed boundary on specific date & time information?

Comment: If user will turn off location services for application you will get nothing. 
You should check this case and ask user to turn on location services.

Comment: From my experience near one year ago this functionality is not stable. 
Of course it possible that I done something wrong (we have a very specific algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need method of CLLocationManager class:

```
- (void)startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

Parameters
region
The region object that defines the boundary to monitor. This parameter must not be nil.
Discussion
You must call this method once for each region you want to monitor. If an existing region with the same identifier is already being monitored by the app, the old region is replaced by the new one. The regions you add using this method are shared by all location manager objects in your app and stored in the monitoredRegions property.

Region events are delivered to the locationManager:didEnterRegion: and locationManager:didExitRegion: methods of your delegate. If there is an error, the location manager calls the locationManager:monitoringDidFailForRegion:withError: method of your delegate instead.

An app can register up to 20 regions at a time. In order to report region changes in a timely manner, the region monitoring service requires network connectivity.

Comment: Thanks. So having limit of 20, app can only notify for 20 near by cities. Also want to confirm What if my app is closed and  locationManager:didEnterRegion event get delivered to my app? Comes to foreground or just i have to show local notification?